# How to Subscribe window.resize from an angular Service?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have tried ,

WindowService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

interface WindowSize {
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WindowService {
  webWindow = window;
  windowHeight: number;
  windowWidth: number;
  windowSize: number;
  constructor() {

    this.getWindowSize = this.getWindowSize.bind(this);

  }


  getWindowSize(): Observable<any> {
    return this.webWindow.addEventListener('resize', ()=> {
      this.windowSize = {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
      };
      return this.windowSize;
    });
  }
}
```

Component Where i am trying to subscribe the getWindowSize method

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadUser();
    this.windowSize = this.windowService.getWindowSize().subscribe(data=> {
      console.log(data)
      this.windowSize = data;
    }); 
  }
```

Error I am Getting is

> AppComponent.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'subscribe' of undefined
>       at FeedlistComponent.ngOnInit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a service that would also not throw any errors in server side environment and does not leak subscriptions:

```js
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common';
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {fromEvent, NEVER, Observable} from 'rxjs';

// @dynamic
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ResizeService extends Observable<Event> {
    private readonly resize$: Observable<Event>;

    constructor(
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) {defaultView}: Document,
    ) {
        super(subscriber => this.resize$.subscribe(subscriber));

        this.resize$ = defaultView ? fromEvent(defaultView, 'resize') : NEVER;
    }
}
```

**Note**: comment `// @dynamic` is important, otherwise AOT builds fail with `Document` type in constructor arguments.

**Note**: You might also consider throttling those events.

Usage:

```js
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(@Inject(ResizeService) resize$: Observable<Event>) {
        resize$.subscribe(console.log);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

addEventListener doesn't return an observable. You can use `fromEvent(window, 'resize')`. [Here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html) is the documentation for `fromEvent`.